# Div responsive like an img

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I have an img if I give it a width:100%; and no height. When the window change, the width adapts to its parent and the height keeps the proportion. Can I make a div behave the same way?

For different reasons, I need the div be the width and height than the img. In this case, the img original size is 600 x 300 px.

The example here to play: http://jsfiddle.net/r05zpdd0/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_sticker.png"/>
<div id="nota">some text</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}

div {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;

    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: A div does behave the same way, with the exception that its contents does not scale when the parent is resized. Are you asking for a way to keep the aspect-ratio of a div at a certain relationship?

Comment: @shennan yep he is, there's already a post on it so I linked to it in my answer :)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r05zpdd0/1/?

Comment: I am sorry, now I see my question is a duplicate. What should I do now?

Comment: @Nrc don't worry, you can leave your post like this, it will act as a pointer to the "main" one.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. CSS:

```
    img {
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
    }

    div.wrap{
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:100%;
        padding-top:50%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        background: blue;
    }

    div#nota
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_sticker.png"/>
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="nota">some text</div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nfvksydp/

So I had to create a wrapper around your #nota div which is positioned relative. This allows the #nota div to be positioned absolutely within this div. The wrap div has a padding-top of 50% meaning that the height of the div will always be 50% that of the width.